# OWA traffic block at firewall due DATA URL Scheme Policy bridging

Tags: sharepoint, firewall

We are using SharePoin 2013SP1 in-premise with OWA-2013, WOPIZone is set to external-http in SP, view/editing/adding of office files works behind the load-balancer (LB) but when viewing from client (outside LB) blank page is displayed for any office files.

When launching the URL of OWA check "http:///hosting/discovery" from the client I get the XML file displayed on the client browser.

Check the OWA and SP logs and could not find any exception, the file checking is performed and replied successfully (compared this with a good request and failure request both seams same).
hence requested network team to check on firewall, who has given the below info.

### Network Findings:

we found that IPS signature **HTTP: RFC 2397 Data URL Scheme Policy blocked** the traffic.
It was found that the reply from server was blocked due to DATA URI packet is transferred which is blocked at firewall.

### Question:

1) Can provide more info on this DATA URI base64 encoding data reply from OWA server. When network team want to open this policy what info I should provide (origin source, uni/bi drection, etc).
2) Any other such policy to be opened for view/adding/editing office files using OWA from client.
3) In the event this rule/policy is marked as "HIGH" in terms of security then any other work-around for viewing office files through OWA.
Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Hi, maybe this Exchange site is more useful: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ 
I also notice your URL has 3 slashes, "http:///" ¿have you tried with 2 slashes?

Comment: Thanks. that was type error. the OWA http://<domain>/hosting/discovery works. but when viewed from SP2013 it does not opens office file. Reason blocked by firewall.

Comment: You welcome. I don't know anything about SP, OWA, and not much about firewalls, but ill suggest trying to capture the request made by SP2013 and check the firewall rules to try understanding why it's being blocked. Maybe the firewall needs a explicit rule for your host, or port, and if not, is getting into a default "deny anything not listed before this rule". Also consider the  sharepoint.stackexchange.com because maybe there is already an anwser to this or they can help you better. Good luck

Comment: thanks. let me check.

Comment: OWA refers to office web apps. Not outlook web apps

Comment: I removed the outlook tag and added some for sharepoint and firewall, I hope that brings better visibility for the question. I didn't found any "office-web-app" tag, there was a "office-web-component" one, but i don't really know if it fits here.

Comment: Thanks. its SharePoint 2013 with Office-Web-Apps.